# Updating List<object> in codebehind and forcing bindings in XAML to update

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, code-behind

I have a method that populates a List with 5 random images. The method returns correctly. When I call the method to populate the List before `this.InitializeComponent();` in the codebehind, the images appear on screen. However, when I call the method afterwards, it has no effect on what is shown on screen. What can I do to fix this? It seems like I need to call `RaisePropertyChanged()` or something along these lines, but I can't find a way to do this. Can anyone please help ?

In my code behind I have the code :

```
 public List<BitmapImage> listOfImages { get; set; }

  private async void Get_Images(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //code to get 5 random images
            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();
            listOfImages = new List<BitmapImage>();
            foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
            {
                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.SetSource(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
                listOfRelatedImages.Add(src);
            }
        }
```

And in my XAML :

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listOfImages}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Image x:Name="images" Source="{Binding}" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill">
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Keep `listOfImages` as `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of List

ItemsControl track collection changes(add/remove/reset/move) with INotifyCollectionChanged interface, so if you want ItemsControl to update automatically, you need to implement this interface on the list. WPF already contains generic collection that implement this interface.

Replace

```
List<BitmapImage> listOfImages
```

With

```
ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> listOfImages
```

And it should work

Answer (score 3):

To let the Datagrid know about changes in your List (e.g. add() or remove()) you have to use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

If you want to inform the DataGrid about changes inside the list (e.g. changing properties) the class shown in the DataGrid has to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface